# mongodb sum query returning zero

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection *balance* with records

```
{  
 "_id" : "uezyuLx4jjfvcqMXN",   
  "amount" : "10",   
"createdBy" : "AGuT6zQtSojvozbbg"   
}
{  
 "_id" : "dCC8GrNdEjym3ryua",   
"amount" : "10",  
"createdBy" : "AGuT6zQtSojvozbbg"  
}
```

I'm trying to calculate sum of amounts:

```
db.balance.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$createdBy",total:{ $sum: "$amount"}}}])
```

Expected output:

```
{createdBy:AGuT6zQtSojvozbbg , total:20}
```

Actual output:

```
{ "_id" : "AGuT6zQtSojvozbbg", "total" : 0 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have string values in `amount` field. From documentation of [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/):

> Calculates and returns the sum of *numeric* values. $sum ignores
>   non-numeric values.

And returning zero is an expected behavior:

> If all operands are non-numeric, $sum returns 0.

You should convert field value from string to number:

```
db.balance.find({amount: {$type:"string"}}).forEach(function(doc) { 
    var amountInt = new NumberInt(doc.amount);
    db.balance.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {amount: amountInt}});
});
```

After that your query will work fine. The only thing you will need to add is projection stage to rename _id field to createdBy.